# Hibernate second level cache - multiple objects of the same entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, caching

I need to ensure that only one object of the same entity is created (as it is done when loading data using first level hibernate cache, to simplify entity refreshing) and I want to use second level cache.

Im testing ehcache but cant make it working. Normally the entities in my app are being nested in other entities but this is just an simple example of usage:

a) example using first level cache which works fine:

```
 session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
 transaction = session.getTransaction();
 transaction.begin();
 Person person=session.get(Person.class, 1L);
 Person person2=session.get(Person.class, 1L);
 transaction.commit();
 session.close();

 System.out.println(person2 == person);
```

and it returns true

b) using second level cache with Ehcache

```
//1. load person with id 1
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
transaction = session.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
Person person=session.get(Person.class, 1L);
transaction.commit();
session.close();

//2. load the same person
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
transaction = session.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
Person person2=session.get(Person.class, 1L);
transaction.commit();
session.close();

System.out.println(person2 == person);
```

and it returns false

Is it normal behaviour of second level cache to be like that or do i miss something?
Does any second level cache engine keep only one instance of the same entity (as first level cache do)?

Comment: HAve a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache). I guess your configuration is wrong, but since you haven't posted that, its impossible to tell

Comment: I am still not sure how it should work, it seems to work as if I change something in database and tries to refresh entity, it returns cache value instead of real, modified value in database but... Can I make it done that as in my example person2 as object == person (avoid multiple instances of the same entity/row in database)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to keep one instance of the entity in RAM in Hibernate using second level cache as each time Hibernate find it in the cache, it just creates new instance based on the cached data.

For my purpose I have implemented AVL Tree based loaded entities and database synchronization engine that creates repositiories based on the loaded entities from hibernate and asynchronously search throught all the fields in entities and rewrites/merge all the same fields (so that if some field (pk) is the same entity like the one in repository, it replaces it)

In this way synchronization with database is easy as it comes to find the externally changed entity in the repository (so basically in the AVL Tree which is O(log n)) and rewrite its fields.